# Haskell - Max number in a list

Tags: haskell

I want to find the maximum integral value in a list of integers. The following is my code -

```
maximum :: [Int] -> Int
maximum [x] = x
maximum (x:xs) =
 | (maximum xs) > x = maximum xs
 | otherwise = x
```

I do NOT want to use the in-built function max. So, I have NOT used :
maximum (x:xs) = max x (maximum xs)

Why is the code not executing ?

Comment: "not executing" Please tell us what you're seeing, not what you're not seeing. If there's an error, post it.

Comment: parse error on input '|'

Comment: I have ensured proper indentation just like in the above code

Comment: Yep, I get that parse error too. A quick comparison to http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions would suggest that the line before the pattern guards should not end with `=`.

Comment: @YannVernier : Such a silly mistake by my side. You were right. Removing "=" did the trick. Thankyou

Answer (score 12):

You should remove the `=` before the wards block.
Now, for making your function properly:

You can `fold` the list:

```
maximum' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum' = foldr1 (\x y ->if x >= y then x else y)
```

For the recursive version (no double checking):

```
maximum'' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum'' [x]       = x
maximum'' (x:x':xs) = maximum' ((if x >= x' then x else x'):xs)
```

If you want wards:

```
maximum'' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum'' [x]       = x
maximum'' (x:x':xs) | x >= x'   = maximum' (x:xs)
maximum'' (x:x':xs) | otherwise = maximum' (x':xs)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/K3qe/1)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was looking for the guards version.  However, the patterns are non exhaustive.  I can't figure out what to return for [].  Thanks for helping us newbs!

Comment: @JayImerman, in that case change the signature to return a `Maybe`. in the case of `[]` return `Nothing`, otherwise as shown here wrapped in `Just`

Comment: Or, I just came across this in the learning material, add a guard for []:   maximum' [] = error "You can't get max of an empty list"

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra `=` before the first `|`.

```
maximum (x:xs) | (maximum xs) > x = maximum xs
               | otherwise        = x
```

Note that you compute `maximum xs` twice which will probably make your code run **very** slowly.

Comment: It's still not ideal because unless haskell does some magic common expression elimination it's going to be exponential (`maximum xs` is called twice!).

Comment: Crap. Somehow I didn't see it. My bad.

Comment: if you factored it out, would that solve the problem? i.e. if you add `where myMax = maximum xs` at the bottom, then replace both the `maximum xs` with the new variable `myMax`. Made it much faster my side

Comment: @13sen1 Yes it should speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is a syntax error, you need to remove the `=` after `maximum (x:xs)`.

Secondly, the function `maximum` conflicts with `Main.maximum`, I suggest you rename it, for example:

```
maximum' :: [Int] -> Int
maximum' [x] = x
maximum' (x:xs)
 | (maximum' xs) > x = maximum' xs
 | otherwise = x
```

Comment: It's perfectly commonplace to define functions whose names conflict with standard or even Prelude ones. Just `import Prelude hiding (maximum)`.

Comment: Yes of course - just trying to reduce potential for confusion for those new to Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion

Using `where` Clause

```
maxrec :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
maxrec [] = error "maximum of empty list"
maxrec [x] = x
maxrec (x:xs)
  | x > maxTail = x
  | otherwise = maxTail
  where maxTail = maxrec xs
```